# Erasing the Find/Replace History on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, replace

I've looked around online to try to find a way to delete the history of VS 2010's Find/Replace feature, but all I've gotten are answers only valid for previous versions (VS 05, VS 08, etc.). Does anyone know how clear it for the 2010 version?
Thanks!

Comment: May we know _WHY_ you would ever want to do that?

Comment: A buddy of mine pranked me by having VS find a bunch of expletives while I was away from my computer, so now when I use the find/replace feature it shows all the terms he searched for. I'd like to have those not show up anymore.

Comment: Useful if you've had to search for a sensitive piece of information that you'd now like removed from the find history.

Answer (score 26):

Open `regedit.exe`, go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Find`.  Remove all keys that starts with `Find` and `Replace`, like `Find1`, `Find2`, `Replace1`, etc. You can remove history for `Find` only or `Replace` only, or remove only particular `Find`, if you want to.

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER` user is for user that is currently logged in.

If you need to clear history for another user, you need to go to `HKEY_USERS\{UserId}\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Find`

For example `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-2705333110-2095705488-3072420928-1000\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Find`.

**[EDIT]**

Step-by-step:

1. Make a quick console application:

   ```
   using Microsoft.Win32;

   public static void Main()
   {
       var findKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Find", true);
       findKey.GetValueNames()
           .Where(arg => Regex.IsMatch(arg, @"^Find( \d+)?$"))
           .ToList()
           .ForEach(findKey.DeleteValue);
   }
   ```
2. Compile it and close VS.
3. Run the compiled exe.
4. Open VS - Find history is empty.

Keep in mind that VS caches this `Find` and `Replace` lists. It persists the lists to the registry when you close VS. So if you clean the list and then restart VS, you will see no effect, because VS restored the list on the shutdown. So you need to close VS, clear the list, open VS.

Comment: I've already tried that, and there was no /Find that I could see. Is that the only way?

Comment: @Alex Flores - this is where VS stores those values. Manual registry edit is not the only way to clear this storage. There are 3rd party tool for this too, but all of them will basically clear these registry keys.

Comment: +1 Thanks! If you are using Visual Studio 2012, the you can find the settings in your registry at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\Find`.

Comment: Make sure to close Visual Studio before making these registry edits.

Comment: Jesse Webb in visual studio 2015 this deletes all your custom filters, But you can just define them again (correctly this time)

Comment: How about in visual studio 2022?

Answer (score 7):

My 2 cents - if all else fails, just try searching a lot of different terms yourself. There is a limit on how many searches it remembers, and eventually your own searches will push the unwanted ones off the list.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 shows 20 items in the history. Search for more than that and the unwanted ones will be pushed off the end.

Comment: Valid solution if your permissions do not allow the use of regedit.

Answer (score 6):

For Visual Studio 2017:

http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/2017/07/15/about-the-new-privateregistry-bin-file-of-visual-studio-2017/
https://github.com/Microsoft/VSProjectSystem/blob/master/doc/overview/examine_registry.md

Extract:

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Start Regedit.exe
3. Select the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE node
4. From the main menu, select File -> Load Hive... and select the private registry file. That file is stored in the Local App Data %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\[config]\privateregistry.bin where [config] corresponds to the configuration hive you would like to browse
5. It will prompt for a name - that represents the name that will be displayed under (e.g. IsolatedHive)
6. Now you should be able to browse the registry under the hive you created
   Now search for the key "Find" and delete whatever you need to delete.
7. Before launching Visual Studio, you need to unload it: From the main menu File -> Unload Hive before attempting to run VS (otherwise regedit keeps the file locked, and Visual Studio will fail to launch)